# Linq to SQL Distinct Value Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I wish to use a linq to sql query that I then turn into a dictionary of distinct values. Both the key and value will come from the query..

```
var model = db.LANDGRID_PLSS_SECTIONS
                .Select(x => new {x.MERIDIAN_CODE,x.MERIDIAN})
                .ToDictionary(kvp=> kvp.MERIDIAN_CODE as string, kvp=> kvp.MERIDIAN as string)
                .Distinct();
```

This returns an exception saying that an item key with that value already exists.

This dictionary will need to be of type `Dictionary<string,string>`

**UPDATE**

In the table, the MERIDIAN_CODE will always have the same MERIDIAN value. It does however occur multiple times in the table. The Meridian is a user friendly version of the code. I need both available to me in the View.

Comment: What do you want to get when you have the same keys for different value? Maybe you should convert to `Lookup` instead of `Dictionary`?

Comment: Keys in a dictionary must be unique. It sounds like you're getting the same key with different values from your query.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure the query returns only distinct values and then convert to dictionary?

Comment: Which of the duplicates will you keep? Whichever one happens to be encountered first?

Comment: Does the table contain duplicate MERIDIAN_CODE values?

Comment: the duplicates should all be the same. 1 key will have 1 value.. I just have a table full of them amongst other data that varies... I know this isnt normalized but the table is what it is...

Comment: The MERIDIAN_CODE occurs multiple times in the table. But that MERIDIAN_CODE will be always have the same MERIDIAN value every time. Consider one to be a user friendly name to the other. I need them both for my view. 1 will be the label the other is the actual value entered in the form. I want to include both in the model rather then hardcode the mapping in the application.

Comment: You need to move your call to `Distinct()` **before** calling `ToDictionary`.

Comment: ive tried that as well, still have exceptions

Comment: GroupBy instead of select

Comment: The code should work.  It is possible the duplicattes are due to upp/lower case letters, or spaces in some of the keys.  So using Trim() and ToLower() may help remove the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var model = db.LANDGRID_PLSS_SECTIONS
    .GroupBy(s => s.MERIDIAN_CODE, s => s.MERIDIAN)
    .ToDictionary(s => s.Key, v => v.First());
```

Comment: That means you have some entries with null values in sections.

Comment: right you are! this worked once I corrected the nulls.